# how to read image from local and convert it into file object using node.js

Tags: node.js, rest, express, multipartform-data, fs

I have a .png file in my node project folder and I want to read that file and send that file to a remote REST api which accepts form-data format and returns the image url after uploading it to S3.

I have previously used the same api for image upload in front-end using JavaScript. In my JS application I was using input type file to upload a image, which was giving me image in file format and then I was passing that to api after adding that file into formData object like this:

`let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("content_file", file)`

but when I'm trying to do the same in node.js, I'm not able to read that file into file format, due to which Api is not accepting the request body. 
I'm new to node js, I'm not even sure that I'm reading the file in right way or not. Please help!

```js
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var Request = require("request");
var FormData = require('form-data');
var app = express();

// for reading image from local
app.get('/convertHtml2image1', function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(`image_path`, (err, data) => {
        if (err) res.status(500).send(err);
        let extensionName = path.extname(`banner.png`);
        let base64Image = new Buffer(data, 'binary').toString('base64');
        let imgSrcString = `data:image/${extensionName.split('.').pop()};base64,${base64Image}`;

        // for converting it to formData
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("content_file", data)
        
        // for calling remote REST API
        Request.post({
            "headers": { "token": "my_token" },
            "url": "api_url",
            "body": formData
        }, (error, response, body) => {
            if (error) {
                return console.log(error);
            }
            let result = JSON.parse(body)
            res.send("image_url: " + result.url)
        });
    })
})

app.listen(5000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of fs.readFile() use fs.createReadStream() and don't upload image inside file stream, first read the file then add it to formData and then upload(or send it to api) because instead of file you were uploading the stream here.

```js
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var Request = require("request");
var FormData = require('form-data');
var app = express();

app.get('/convertHtml2image', function (req, res) {
    
    var formData = {
        name: 'content_file',
        content_file: {
            value: fs.createReadStream('banner.png'),
            options: {
                filename: 'banner.png',
                contentType: 'image/png'
            }
        }
    };

    Request.post({
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            "token": my_token
        },
        "url": api_url,
        "formData": formData
    }, (error, response, body) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log("Error: ", error);
        }
        let result = JSON.parse(body)
        res.send("image_url: " + result.url)
    });
})

app.listen(5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you try to create Blobs in Nodejs. It is not defined but it is basically an arraybuffer with file information. Maybe, you can use an external npm package to make it blob. [Check this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/Blob)

Comment: Yes you are right, I didn't knew the exact word for it thanks.

Comment: Okay I'll try this, and let you know

Comment: It's not a new library but you can find others. In worst case, check the blobs structure and define one yourself. It's just arraybuffer and file type basically.